# Inserting the data in an autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following script that let's me insert a line in a text file:

```
^1::
     InputBox, text, fire writing, What did you achieve today?
     file := FileOpen("log.txt", "a")
     file.write(text "`n") 
     file.Close()
 return
```

I would now like to add a date to this so I get DDMMYYYY - mytext. Any thoughts on the edits I should make to this script so I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To format a date with AutoHotkey have a look at the documentation for [FormatTime](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm).

It takes the following arguments, where `Format` is the one you're looking to modify:

> FormatTime, OutputVar , YYYYMMDDHH24MISS, Format

In your case your script would look somewhat like the following:

```
^1::
     FormatTime, TimeString,, ddMMyyyy
     InputBox, text, fire writing, What did you achieve today?
     file := FileOpen("log.txt", "a")
     file.write(TimeString . " - " . text "`n") 
     file.Close()
 return
```